# c++ sorting class vector

Tags: c++, class, sorting, qsort

I have a class `sort_map`:

```
class sort_map {
    char key;
    int val;
    sort_map(int v, char k): key(k), val(v){}
};
using namespace std; 
int comp_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(sort_map*)b).val - (*(sort_map*)a).val);
} 
int main () {
    vector <sort_map> v; 
    v.push_back(5, 'a');
    v.push_back(67, 'd');
    v.push_back(2, 'c');
    v.push_back(98, 'f'); 
    return 1;
}
```

**I want to order the vector by val using `qsort`**, and it is not working.

```
qsort(&v.begin(), v.size(), sizeof(sort_map), comp_int);
```

But when I use this, it works

```
qsort(&v[0], v.size(), sizeof(sort_map), comp_int);
```

Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead

Comment: As for why? `&v.begin()` gets the address of the iterator, not the data the iterator references. `qsort` is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: *I want to order the vector by val using qsort* -- No, forget it.  Use `std::sort`.  And if this is a "requirement for your assignment to use `qsort`", [look here](http://ideone.com/g8tiPK).  That return value of 0 from `std::is_pod` shows that you cannot sort `sort_map` using qsort without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming we just ignore the compilation errors, as everything in `sort_map` is private and `comp_int` isn't friended.

Comment: why `return 1;` at the end?

Comment: Your life would be easier if you defined `operator<` inside your class.  Also define `operator==`.

Comment: BTW, your constructor `sort_map` is `private` by default, since you are using a `class`.  You may want to make it `public` by using `public:` or change to a `struct`.

Comment: @EissaN.:  The return of 1 indicates that `a > b`.  This is the same ordering rules for `strcmp`.  Here are the results: 1) `a == b` return 0.  2) `a < b` return less than 0.  3) `a > b` return greater than zero.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I meant the one at the end of the main().

Comment: @ssgakhal Do you wonder why `&v[0]` works but not `&v.begin()`?

Comment: @ssgakhal `v.begin()` returns a temporary iterator object and taking address of a temporary object is not meaningful. But, `v[0]` refers to the first element so `&v[0]` refers to the address of the first element.

Comment: thanks its very usefull user4581301 and Eissa N.

Comment: Why? It's a bad answer. It it works, it's only by dumb luck. Bad luck.

Comment: I don't know why there is even an answer attempted for this question when the final outcome using `qsort` is UB.

Comment: user4581301 You've taken my doubt, its very useful your explanation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
sort_map* ptr1 = &v[0];
sort_map* ptr2 = &v.begin();
```

And you'll find which one gets compiled, and would find that these expressions are not equal.

First statement would compile since the type of `v[0]` is `sort_map`, hence `&a` applied on it would make it

`sort_map*`

Second statement's base type is `vector<sort_map>::iterator`, and its address would be

`iterator*`

for this `vector` type. As you can see `iterator*` cannot be assigned to `sort_map*` - they are not similar.

`qsort` takes `void*` without enforcing any **type-safety** from the compiler. A `void*` can be passed any type of pointer without any typecast needed, hence it compiles well. You are passing a wrong thing to `qsort`. As others recommended, you better use `std::sort`